# setTimeout function on a <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on my own portfolio and I want to put a delay between 2 pages with a setTimeout function. I've tried some ways but haven't worked yet. I am already using a function to open my "href" with all my box but now I just want to put a delay to go from accueil.html to presentation.html.

"accueil.html":

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.ouverture');
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
  {
    var item = items[i];
    item.addEventListener('click', function()
    {
      var url = this.getElementsByTagName('a');

      url = url[0];
      window.location = url;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box-part text-center ouverture">
          <i class="fa fa-address-book fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <div class="title">
            <h4><a href="presentation.html" id="pres">Présentation</a></h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `timeout` add the part where you redirect to another page:

```js
item.addEventListener('click', function() {         
  var url = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
  if(url.length > 0)
    url = url[0]; 
    setTimeOut(() => {
      window.location = url;
    }, 2000); // 2000 = 2000ms === 2sec   
});
```

More info is found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: Thank you Stefan ! I knew it was a timeout but didn't know how to place it in my function. If I want to put a fadeOut on my box, I just have to add it in my "setTimeOut())" function right ?

Answer (score 0):

A general-purpose snippet that "delays" clicks. Just add the script at the top of the page and use the `delay-click[=numberOfMilliseconds]` attribute.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  var currentTarget = target.closest("[delay-click]:not(.delay-click-ignore)");

  if (!currentTarget) return;

  var delay = +currentTarget.getAttribute("delay") || 2000;
  currentTarget.classList.add("delay-click-ignore");

  setTimeout(function() {
    target.click();
    currentTarget.classList.remove("delay-click-ignore");
  }, delay);

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.delay-click-ignore,
.delay-click-ignore a,
.delay-click-ignore input,
.delay-click-ignore button {
  cursor: progress !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="box">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box-part text-center ouverture">
          <i class="fa fa-address-book fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <div class="title">
            <!-- on the element itself -->
            <h4><a href="presentation.html" delay-click>default delay</a></h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <!-- or somewhere up the ranks -->
        <div class="box-part text-center ouverture" delay-click=5000>
          <i class="fa fa-address-book fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <div class="title">
            <h4><a href="presentation.html">delay 5s</a></h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box-part text-center ouverture">
          <i class="fa fa-address-book fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <div class="title">
            <h4><a href="presentation.html" id="pres">immediate</a></h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <!-- works here too -->
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" delay-click />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```